# sqlite3 error when attempting to insert info, incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in sqlite with some data in a .txt file. I am using python, and this is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('TEST_Inventory.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InventoryData''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE `InventoryData` (
    `INV_ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `Inventory_Name`    TEXT)''')

fname = ('NameINV.txt')
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    name = line.split()
    print name
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO InventoryData (Inventory_Name) 
        VALUES ( '?' )''', (name,))
    cur.commit()
```

However, every time I try to run this code I get this error:

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql statements can be constructed in 2 ways.

1. By concatenating string (unsafe, easy for sql injection attacks)
   ex: `sql_string = 'INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL1, COL2) VALUES(\'' + value1 + '\',\'' + value2 + '\')'`
2. By using placeholders and bind variables (recommended)
   ex: `sql_string = 'INSERT INTO TABLE_1(COL1,COL2) VALUES (?,?)'` and supply bind variables as `(value1,value2)`

When you use bind variables, there is no need to quote them (to identify them as string/text data). Bind variables will be substituted at database, during execution of statement.

To answer precisely, when you use single-quote around placeholder `'?'`, it will be treated as a text and program doesn't know where to bind the data you supplied while executing query. Just use `?` without quotes, so that, parser finds placeholders to substitute with data and code will execute.

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO InventoryData (Inventory_Name) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', (name,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the placeholder; quoting is taken care of by the database driver when replacing the placeholder with the value:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO InventoryData (Inventory_Name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', (name,))
```